# Firebase not working on script but on main html it does (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

after pasting the given data of my database, doing

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
window.db = firebase.database().ref();
window.db.once('value', snap => data = snap.val());
console.log(data);
```

retrieves correctly the data and its shown as i want, but making a function on a index.js

```
function extend(){
  window.db.once('value', snap => data = snap.val());
  console.log(data);
}
extend();
```

gives me this error
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
at extend (index.js:59)
at index.js:61

I dont get why it would work outside the function and not inside, given that window.db is a global instance, i've tried a couple of ways differently without success, would somebody help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `data` is not defined in the `extend()` function (unless it's some global variable, extend()). You'll get better results if you refactor your code like so:

```js
// Define the local variable
function extend(){
   window.db.once('value', snap => {
      let data = snap.val();
      console.log(data);
   });
}
extend();
```